# Best Practice for WCF Entity Validation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm currently creating a WCF Service and this is just a read-only service, meaning there's no write access allowed on the service. The WCF Service will use the Employee entity (below) as data object as i'm using entity framework. My question is, what would be the best practice for handling the validation for Employee entity? Should I use dataannotation? or should i let the entity framework just throw the error?

Does WCF Service entities perform validation,when the request is proxied into the Entity Framework?

```
public class Employee{

   public int EmployeeId {get; set}
   public string EmployeeName{get; set}
}
```

Comment: If it's a read only service, why do you need validation?

Comment: @Wouter- I'm just thinking of making it flexible in case they decided to create another UI (ASP.NET MVC) that will use the said service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use data annotation to verify that your input respects your domain, like for example verify that mandatory fields are valorized and that data type and format is correct, etc.. You can add also validation method to the data contract model to check for example if some fields must respect a particular range of data.

This kind of validation can be usefull because it can reduce the number of database access, but if you need to check the existence of the Employee in your database you need to let Entity Framework try to get the entity, so when you need to perform validation that can be executed only involving data in database there is no alternatives to execute some queries.